# PHP and max_input_vars configuration

Tags: php, attack-vector

I am looking into php's [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) setting

> How many input variables may be accepted (limit is applied to $_GET,
>   $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately). Use of this directive
>   mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash
>   collisions. If there are more input variables than specified by this
>   directive, an E_WARNING is issued, and further input variables are
>   truncated from the request.

Basically I understand that this limits the amount of variables someone can send with POST/GET and truncates them if more are given (with warning raised).

What stays unclear is how someone can use post parameters to create

> the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash collisions

Also does it make sense to substantially decrease the number there. If for example in my application I never use more than 20 `POST` variables, can I change `max_input_vars` to say 30? If so, what improvements will I get?

If it makes a difference, I am using  `php 5.5.10` on apache `2.4.7`

Comment: an example of such an hash coalition is found here http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1164260 and a post content to provoke it might be this https://github.com/koto/blog-kotowicz-net-examples/blob/master/hashcollision/2to14.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be not as good in explaining the concept of an hash collision as good as this [external doc](http://www.slideshare.net/ionutberescu/collision-vulnerability-in-hash-data-structures-denial-of-service-attack) so if it becomes not clear you can have a look at it.

In principle the POST and GET data is using a key-value structure. When receiving the data in a request and when accessing $_POST then php will need to convert the list given as a string which could look like this

```
EzEzEzEzEzEzEzEz=&EzEzEzEzEzEzEzFY=&EzEzEzEzEzEzEzG8=&EzEzEzEzEzEzEzH%17=&EzEzEzEzEzEzFYEz=&EzEzEzEzEzEzFYFY=&EzEzEzEzEzEzFYG8=&EzEzEzEzEzEzFYH%17=&EzEzEzEzEzEzG8Ez=&EzEzEzEzEzEzG8FY=&EzEzEzEzEzEzG8G8=&
```

into a form so taht you can do for instance this:

```
echo $_POST["EzEzEzEzEzEzEzEz"];
```

the string is not ideal to access the value, so that internally a hash-function is used to transform it to a resulting hash value. 
The problem and potential attack that [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) could prevent is that
related to the case that two keys generate the same hash-value hence a hash_collision, which causes extra time to care for such a coallision and would allow to use up lots of CPU with a rather simple HTTP request.